# The requested URL /undefined was not found on this server

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have the following code:

```
<a class="quickrate lightGreyBtn" href="selectmovie.php">Launch Quick Rate</a>

//this is inside my javascript
$(".lightGreyBtn").click(function() {
        $.fancybox({
               'width' : '75%',
               'height' : '75%',
               'autoScale' : false,
               'transitionIn' : 'none',
               'transitionOut' : 'none',
               'type' : 'iframe'
        });

        return false;
    });
```

When I click on the button I get the error:

```
The requested URL /undefined was not found on this server.
```

Here's what I have in my selectmovie.php

```
<body id="quickstart">
        <div id="dialog" style="display: block;">
            <div>
                <h1><strong>Rate <span class="number">10</span> movies you like</strong> and start finding new favorites.</h1>
                <ul class="items">
                    <li data-page="1">
                        <ul class="clearfix quickstart objects">
                                <?php
                                    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;",'root','test');
                                    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                                    $db->beginTransaction();
                                    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT MID, TITLE, URL FROM movie WHERE YEAR = ? AND URL != ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8");    
                                    $result->execute(array(2011, 'http://cdn-5.nflximg.com/us/boxshots/large/70144645.jpg'));
                                    $movies = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
                                    foreach ($movies as $movie)
                                    {

                                        //create some html code using echo here
                                    }
                                ?>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <a href="#" data-page="1" data-nexttoken="1301018340333" data-total="135" data-seed="1301018340333" class="next newBlue">More Movies »</a>
            </div>
        </div>


</body>
```

What is the issue?

Comment: What's giving you the error: PHP or JS?

Comment: that's what I am trying to figure out.. it pops out the fancybox and that error I got is inside the fancy box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `href` property in the object passed to `$.fancybox`. Try adding this after `'type' : 'iframe'` (you'll need a comma after `'iframe'`, too, of course):

```
'href' : $(this).attr('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

try using absolute path instead of relative path !

try checking the Apache error log, perhaps you can get some more info about the error there.
try running only the PHP script and check if it succeed !